# Where can I get springseed?

Tags: 13.10

The website http://getspringseed.com/ as links to .deb files to install it, but clicking them only gets me a 404 error. Where can I get a copy of it? Is there a repo for it? Has it been posted anywhere else on the web?

Also: What should I tag this question with? Or does it not belong on this site?

Comment: Probably belongs in their Github issue tracker, but it's [already there](https://github.com/michealharker/springseed/issues/119).

Answer (score 1):

In the [project's github website](https://github.com/michealharker/springseed) you can download the source code and compile it yourself. As for the deb's, maybe is just a temporary broken link, so I'd suggest you try again later.